# Can Intel Ironlake graphics support two QHD monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I am running a nine year old [i5-430M](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/mobile-5th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.pdf), 8 GB RAM, Windows 7 with Intel integrated graphics. My graphics card has one HDMI and one VGA port. The laptop specification says:

HDMI v1.3 supporting up to 1080p, 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz DVI mode

VGA (Dsub 15-pin) supporting 1920 x 1200 resolution at 75 Hz

I am already running a 2560*1080 at 60Hz ultra-wide LG monitor (with laptop display shut) on the HDMI port.

I am planning to buy a new 32 inch 2560*1440 monitor and wondering whether my ports can drive it?

***If yes***, can the lone HDMI v1.3 port be used to drive the two monitors? Perhaps using some splitters or connectors (suggest!).

***If no***, then what resolution can be properly run on my second monitor?

PS: I also have one USB 2.0 port free. My needs are purely productivity based. Just want more screen real estate for R studio, word, chrome, and pdf reader. No youtube or gaming needs.

Thanks
Nikhil

Comment: Fun question.  Intel's [specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/43537/intel-core-i5-430m-processor-3m-cache-2-26-ghz.html) don't list supported resolutions for Ironlake (they do for newer generations).  QHD monitors didn't really exist at the time.  I can tell you VGA supports it (up to 85 Hz), and there are some QHD monitors with VGA out there.

Comment: [This review](https://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/core-i5-650-660-and-661-processor-review,2.html) for the desktop equivalent says that the maximum resolution is 2560x1600 and dual output is supported.  That's a good sign.